# Issue with @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite with TestNG plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, testng

I have several suites like Suite1, Suite2, Suite3 and so on. I also have a common suite called CommonSuite which has `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` methods. I have a testng.xml that has all suites configured and I am using maven failsafe plugin to run the tests. Everything works fine.

Now my question is if I want to run/debug say *just* Suite1 using TestNG plugin in eclipse, how do I make sure that my CommonSuite is also included along with Suite1? One dirty way I know is that I can comment all suites that I don't want to run in *testng.xml* and keep only CommonSuite and Suite1 and then run/debug as TestNG suite. Doesn't seem to be the right way of doing this though. Any other better ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi best way to do this is implement a listner class for suits implement ISuiteListener

the basic clas will look like follows

```
    public class PlatformSuite implements ISuiteListener { 

    /**
     * This method is invoked before the SuiteRunner starts.
     */
    public synchronized void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        /*Your before suite implementation here*/
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked after the SuiteRunner has run all
     * the test suites.
     */

    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
         /*Your after suite implementation here*/
    }

}}
```

for eclipse plugin you can specify testng xmal as "Template XML file"

To initiate listener in testng.xml you can add following, remember to ass desable default listener setting

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="DssTestSuite" parallel="false">
    <parameter name="useDefaultListeners" value="false"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.someonr.something.core.PlatformSuite"/>
    </listeners>
<test name="sample Test" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <packages>
    </packages>
    <classes>         
    </classes>
</test>
```

This call will call before each test suite and after each test suite

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36980210/658497 - implementing the same ISuiteListener, just with TestNG @Annotation above the Test class.