# Testng with multiple suites. @AfterSuite method closes driver after 1st suite and 2nd suite can't be run

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I use `testng` for running tests. I have several test suites(*Suite1.xml*, *Suite2.xml* and *Suite3.xml*), which are combined in one suite (*MasterSuite.xml*). Besides those, I have the class `TestBase.java`, where I configure such methods as `@BeforeTest`, `@BeforeMethod`, `@BeforeSuite`, `@AfterSuite`, etc.

Running the `@AfterSuite` method closes the driver (`driver.quit()`).

**What I want:** run `MasterSuite` which will run all my 3 suites one after another.

**The problem:** after the first suite (`Suite1`) is executed, the driver is closed and thus, `Suite2` can't be run.

How can I resolve this issue/problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MasterSuite">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="Suite1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="Suite2.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="Suite3.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run one suite after another and not to run them in parallel, then it should be enough to start your driver in @BeforeSuite method.

In that way all your suites will have separate instance of WebDriver initialized.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove quit method form AfterSuite and Place it after all your test cases in the last suite
2. Make Test cases independent, You can use BeforeMethod and AfterMethod to invoke browser if not and close browser if failure plus the login part if needed, and this can benefit later as you can have independent test cases
3. AfterSuite will be called after each suite is done, so your quit driver is getting called after the first suite is called. You can use BeforeSuite to have a method which will invoke driver if it is not running, Can have a flag which will make sure to launch only one driver if it is not running
4. If it is a small number of test cases, you can get them all together into one test suite and carry on with the same fashion without any issue

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use TestNG Listener [ISuiteListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html).

First, store the Driver as a suite attribute, for example inside @BeforeClass of TestBase:

```
@Listeners({ SuiteListener.class })
public class TestBase {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init(ITestContext testContext) {
        driver = createWebDriver(...);
        ISuite suite = testContext.getSuite();
        suite.setAttribute("driver", driver);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in SuiteListener class, create onFinish() method to get the stored attribute, and close the Driver:

```
public class SuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {

    public WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * This method is invoked after the SuiteRunner (parent suite) has finished to run all the child suites.
     */
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        driver = (WebDriver) suite.getAttribute("driver");
        closeDriverAfterSuite(...);
    }
```